# Racket - Take the integer closest to an inexact value

Tags: racket

Is there any way in Racket to take the integer closest to an inexact value? For example, if I have `#i13.0` as the input, I want `13` as the output. I'm not quite sure where to look for solutions. I attempted using `floor` but that left it as an inexact value, and a simple google search for "racket convert inexact number to exact number" didn't yield any results.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, [`exact-round`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmath..rkt%29._exact-round%29%29)

```
#lang racket
(exact-round #i13.0)
;; 13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `round`.

```
(round #i13.0)
```

Comment: A good thought, but it doesn't work. `(round #i13.0)` for me outputs `#i13.0`